# class="disconnect-collapsed" when pulling twitter profile images

Tags: php, jquery, css, html, twitter

So I'm setting up a live twitter feed that pulls in the ID/user/tweet/profile image.
I have this all coming in fine with an ajax call, but for some reason when I try to display the image a class of "disconnect-collapsed" get applied to the image tag and the image doesn't display. If i inspect the element I can seen the url to the image and its correct. I can click the src and it takes me to the image. here how I'm adding the img tag

```
var profileImg = this.profileImg;
var response = "<div class='tweet' id='"+id+"'><img src='"+profileImg+"' /></div>";

$('#results').prepend(
          $(response).css({
            'background-color' : tweetColour,
            'left': posx+'px',
            'top': posy+'px',
            'display':'none',
            'width': '100px',
            'height' : '100px',
            'z-index' : zIndex
            })
        );
```

Anyone know why the image wouldnt be showing and what "disconnect-collapsed" is doing?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disconnect-collapsed` is applied by the browser extension - [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/).

Answer (score 0):

Further to Deepak Mittal's answer, if you want to show the profile image you can either

1. Uninstall Disconnect

or, if you don't want to do this, you can

1. Go your feed page in Chrome
2. Open the Disconnect panel by clicking on the black **D** icon in Chrome's toolbar
3. At the top there should be a green box with a white Twitter icon and a number greater than 0 next to it
4. Click the Twitter icon and it will turn gray, meaning you have unblocked Twitter